# Print empty string for a missing key and converting the result to CSV

Tags: json, stream, export-to-csv, jq, missing-data

I am trying to convert belowJSON to CSV using jq command but the final CSV is unable to place deviceName field properly as it's missing in some JSON lines.

```
{
  "id": "ABC",
  "deviceName": "",
  "total": 100,
  "master": 20
}
{
  "id": "ABC",
  "total": 100,
  "master": 20
}
```

How can i make sure empty value gets when Key is missing ?.

I Tried below command to generate CSV

```
./jq -r '[.[]] | @csv' > final.csv
```

But it gives CSV like below as you can see when deviceName key is missing in JSON it's cell shifting left side.

```
"ABC","",100,20
"ABC",100,20
```

I want output something like below which adds empty value if deviceName is missing.

```
"ABC","",100,20
"ABC","",100,20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `jq` you can use the alternate operator `//` that can be used to return default values. E.g.  `.foo // 1` will evaluate to `1` if there's no `.foo` element in the input

Using that and appending an empty string `""` if the key is not present, you can do

```
jq -r '[.id // "", .deviceName // "", .total // "", .master // ""] | @csv'
```

**Note**: The alternate operator `.foo // 1` causes the evaluation to `1` for case when the value of `foo` is `null` or `false`. You may wish to modify the above program if your data contains `null` or `false` values.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the first object as a reference for a full record, like

```
keys_unsorted as $k | (., inputs) | [.[$k[]]] | @csv
```

For your sample this produces following

```
"ABC","",100,20
"ABC",,100,20
```